# Restrict Applications access to Device

Tags: windows, gaming, game-controller

I have a PC that has the ability to handle running multiple game clients at once (specifically Tera Online). What I'd like to do is assign and/or restrict each clients access to a device (Gamepad) so that the actions from each device only effects the client I specify.

After doing some research with Python's PyGame, I can see that a Gamepad essentially works like a Keyboard does by sending global key events to the entire system, and then the application reading those events. Question is, how can I make it not global? ONly have one application read one controller? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What version of Windows? i.e. XP has "hardware profiles".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the settings for each game client unbind all the controls and then rebind them on one client for the controller input and keyboard on the other client.

It probably will not save your settings correctly (i.e. it will either save the controller config or keyboard config)

This is a trick we used to use on older games that support joysticks like Day of Defeat. Not certain it will work on Tera Online but should be simliar.